# nurses in a company

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A health care company provides 100 face masks for free to a team of three nurses. In how many ways can the face masks be distributed among the three nurses?

> Nine nurses work for an intensive care unit of a hospital. How many ways can the nine nurses be grouped into three groups of size three each?

The first question should just be the number of ways to choose $3$ objects from $100$ objects since order doesn't matter, right? Then the answer should be ${100\choose 3}.$

For the second question, the order of the groups does not matter, and there are ${9\choose 3} $ ways to choose the nurses for the first group, ${6\choose 3}$ ways to choose them for the second group, and $1$ way to choose them for the third group. So the total number of ways should be $\frac{1}{3!}{9\choose 3}{6\choose 3}$, since order doesn't matter, right?

Comment: I think you need to specify whether the masks are indistinguishable or not. If they are distinguishable, then I believe the answer is $3^{100}$ since each mask can be given to any of the three; if not, then I think the answer should be something like $\binom{103}{3}$ by a stars and bars approach.

Comment: To clarify, I believe your answer for the other part is correct.

Comment: @BelowAverageIntelligence you mean $\binom{102}{2}$.  Recall, we only need two barriers to separate things into three piles, not three.

Comment: sorry, that's right